# How I can keep a seedbed warm till transplant without having the main power on (using solar powerbank)?

Tags: germination

I have a sunny spot in my summer house. But because I visit it once a week it has the main power off. The same is with heating as well.

In this spot I want to place a seeder with total of 24 seeder cups. But despite being sunny I am afraid that seeder will be cold and may I nkt have any success of my seeds being sprout.

Is there a way to use a USB power bank to keep my seeder warm?

I think heating mats need 220V AC that I cannot provide. Can I warm each individual cup with a USB cup warmer or grow lights powered using USB?

Comment: Once per week is not enough water for seedlings unless they are in large containers that can hold sufficient water. And warmth is only for sprouting ; once sprouted they should be cool to avoid becoming too tall.

Comment: I will place automatic watering system. I can keep them watered. Also, I can use a 17liter bucket/Olive oil container as well filled to the brim with water. Using a droplet system I can water them via a watercooling/fishtank pump.

Comment: search for "usb warmer" on amazon, there's all kinds of things you could recruit into heating a tray or individual cups. I would think the hand warmers, heating pads, or mug warming pads might be your best best. you can put a cooking pan, cast iron or aluminum, or some other flat heavy metal object between the bottom of your tray and the heaters to even out the heat from, say 3 hard warmers.

Comment: Heh. The traditional way of keeping seed beds warm is a layer of horse manure under the seedlings. The decay process produces warmth. That's probably not practical here.

Comment: But I have a traditional manure. Though it is digested.